# Android RecyclerView freezes when image loading is done using Picasso

Tags: android, android-layout, picasso, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

In my android app, on homepage there is a recyclerview consisting cardviews as each item. First,I call ParseServer to get data on server and pass it to the recyclerview adapter. I pass image url along with other details to adapter class.
Inside my MainActivity.java

```
Parse.initialize(this, "key1", "key2");
        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                      Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                    } else {
                      Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                    }
            }
        });
        if(haveNetworkConnection()){
                new task().execute();

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Class task which fetches data from server:

```
public class task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{


        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            rel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pro.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            titles.clear();
            images.clear();
            venues.clear();
            timings.clear();
            urgent.clear();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("notices");
                try {
                    List<ParseObject> ob = query.find();
                    for(ParseObject obj:ob){
                        String str = obj.getString("title");
                        String str1 = obj.getString("venue");
                        String str2 = obj.getString("timing");
                        ParseFile file = obj.getParseFile("images");
                        String str3 = obj.getString("urgent");
                        String url;
                        if(file!=null)
                            url = file.getUrl();
                        else{
                            url = "https://www.medidirect.com.au/MEDIstores/_images/no-thumb.png";
                        }
                        titles.add(str);
                        images.add(url);
                        venues.add(str1);
                        timings.add(str2);
                        urgent.add(str3);
                    }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            AdapNotice mAdapter = new AdapNotice(MainActivity.this,titles,images,venues,timings,urgent);
            if(titles.size()<1)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Oops, Something went wrong. Please try again", 300).show();
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            pro.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Inside AdapNotice class which is recyclerview adapter:

```
public class AdapNotice extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapNotice.ViewHolder>{


     Activity activity;
     ArrayList<String> _titles = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> _images = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> _venues = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> _timings = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> _urgents = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int lastPosition = -1;
    int pos;
     public AdapNotice(Activity a, ArrayList<String> titles, ArrayList<String> images, ArrayList<String> venues, ArrayList<String> timings, ArrayList<String> urgent) {
         activity = a;
         _titles = titles;
         _images = images;
         _venues = venues;
         _timings = timings;
         _urgents = urgent;
     }
     public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView title;
         public ImageView imgview,urgent;
         public TextView venue,venuetext,abctext;
         public TextView timing,timingtext,abc1text;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            imgview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_notice);
            venue = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.venue);
            timing = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timing);
            venuetext = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.venuetext);
            abctext = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.abctext);
            timingtext = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.timingtext);
            abc1text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.abc1text);
            urgent = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.urgentstar);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(_titles.size()<=0)
            return 0;
        return _titles.size();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            holder.title.setText(_titles.get(position));
            if(_urgents.get(position).contains("yes")){
                holder.urgent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            pos = position;
            if(!_venues.get(position).contentEquals("---")){
                holder.venuetext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.venue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.abctext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.venue.setText(_venues.get(position));
            }
            if(!_timings.get(position).contentEquals("---")){
                holder.timingtext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.timing.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.abc1text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.timing.setText(_timings.get(position));
            }
            Target target = new Target() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.rotate);
                    holder.imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
                    holder.imgview.startAnimation(anim);

                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap arg0, LoadedFrom arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    holder.imgview.clearAnimation();
                    holder.imgview.setImageBitmap(arg0);
                    Log.i("completed", pos+" completed");
                    storeDB obj = new storeDB(_titles.get(pos), _venues.get(pos), _timings.get(pos), DbBitmapUtility.getBytes(arg0), _urgents.get(pos));
                    obj.execute();
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    holder.imgview.clearAnimation();
                    holder.imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.error);

                }
            };
            Picasso.with(activity).load(_images.get(position)).into(target);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
    private class storeDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        String title,venue,timing,urgent;
        byte[] image;
        public storeDB(String one, String two, String three, byte[] four, String five){
            title = one;
            venue = two;
            timing = three;
            image = four;
            urgent = five;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            SQLiteHandler handler = new SQLiteHandler(activity);
            handler.addNotice(title, venue, timing, image, urgent);
            handler.close();
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int arg1) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.item, parent, false);
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, (arg1>lastPosition)?R.anim.up_from_bottom:R.anim.down_from_top);
            v.startAnimation(animation);
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;

    }
}
```

I pass the image url to picasso library which loads image into target. Till  image is not fetched by picasso, I am showing another loading image and giving it rotate animation effect.

Sometimes, even if image is loaded by picasso, it is not shown in imageview.I know this because on clicking that imageview full image is loaded in another activity which works fine. The rotating animation stops and loaded image also not shown in imageview. Also, the main view freezes sometimes when imageview is being loaded.

So, how can i solve this issue and make my app smoother in operation?

Thanks in advance.

[image: loading animation stops]

**UPDATE** I found out that freezing issue was because of the weak reference to target. I solved it with strong reference but how do I solve hanging issue ? App gets hanged for some time when I am scrolling .

Comment: Picasso already caches images, there is no need to store it in SQLlite, Additionally try downsizing the images your loading into your image views  `Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)`

Comment: I used sqlite for user when he is offline. Cache won't remain there always right ?

Comment: No cache will get cleaned up when the Android system needs to reclaim memory, so if you need SQLlite for storing images take a look at storing blobs.

Comment: I already did that. That works fine. Image is successfully stored as blob

Comment: On main page, I am showing that image in smaller imageview. After clicking that, one another activity opens with full size of image. So how do I manage image loading for both of the sizes if I use .resize ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple approach

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
.error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
.into(imageView);
```

placholder image will be shown before loading the image and error image will be shown if error occur

**UPDATE**
to store in a database just write this much boiler plate code

```
class MyTarget implements Target {

private ImageView imageView;

 public MyTarget(ImageView imageView) {
     this.imageView = imageView;
 }

@Override
 public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
     this.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     //store your bitmap as you were storing 
 }

}
```

and then

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
.error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
.into(new MyTarget(imageView));
```

Comment: Yes I knew that but I want that placeholder image to rotate so that it looks more like loading operation.

Comment: I removed target and directly loaded image to imageview. It is much more smooth now but without target,how do i store loaded image to local db ? I had two purposes for using target, one animation and other store into local db. Even if I remove animation, how do I achieve second purpose ?

Comment: I have updated the code , I know its a compromise , otherwise if you want animation and storing data I would suggest [link](http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-productive-android-developer-part-5-image-loading-library/)

Comment: I think that storing image into sqlite caused little bit hanging in app. I have used asynctask for that still. Can you suggest best method to store image into sqlite ?

Comment: not much of a pro in storing image , try searching on stackoverflow you will find your answer